# Adding and retrieving object of class from file - C++

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I have some code like;

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
class MyClass{
  char mystring[10];
  int mynumber;
 public:
  MyClass(){}
  MyClass(char x[],int y){
    strcpy(mystring,x);
    mynumber = y;
  }
  void disp(void){
    cout<<mystring<<" - "<<mynumber;
  }
  void read(void){
    cout<<"enter char and number\n";
    cin>>mystring>>number;
  }
}

int main(){
  Myclass test[10];

  for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    test[i].read;
    //then store the object into file
  }

  //if user want to display data, then read from file like;
  // string1 - 1234
  // string2 - 3432
  // string9 - 4830

getch();
return 0;

}
```

I want to store some string and an associated number (like a telephone directory) to a file, say `myfile.txt` as binary. The data file may store **objects of** `MyClass`. How can I store info into file and print whole data from file? Need not do file search.

Comment: Use std::string instead of C-style strings.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews could you give me a complete answer, sorry that am a beginner :(

Comment: Why do you want to introduce all the problems of a binary file?  For example, a compiler may add padding between structure members which corrupts the relationship.  Also, text in ASCII is the same as text in binary, occupying the same space.

Comment: what else can I do? I just want to store objects of class into file and retrieve information from there. What are the other possibilities? I would like to implement write() here, thats why..

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to use `std::string`:

```
class Phone_Entry
{
  std::string name;
  std::string phone_number;
};
```

When writing to and reading from a file, you should have the object perform the I/O.
Also, since strings vary in length (a.k.a. variable size record), you will need to either write the length first then the text or write the text with an ending marker.

Let's assume name on one line and phone number on another:

```
class Phone_Entry
{
  // as above
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Phone_Entry& pe);
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Phone_Entry& pe);
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Phone_Entry& pe)
{
  out << pe.name << "\n";
  out << pe.number << "\n";
  return out;
}

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& inp, Phone_Entry& pe)
{
  std::getline(inp, pe.name);
  std::getline(inp, pe.number);
}
```

Now you can use `operator>>` to read your entries from a file:

```
std::ifstream phone_book_file("phone_book.txt");
Phone_Entry entry;
phone_book_file >> entry;
```

Similarly for output:

```
cout << entry;
```

You would benefit greatly by reading the C++ FAQ (search the web for C++ FAQ).